# Cytoscape and linux

Tags: linux, cytoscape

Trying to install Cytoscape program on linux [cytoscape](http://cytoscape.org/download.php).  And I don't know how because first install button transfers me to HTML page and nothing is downloadable. (I have java installed). I tried to download `tar.gz` file but I am stuck, because there is no configure file and it says I have no permission for it. What should I do?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone comes here in search for an answer I found a solution.

You go to you directory where you keep extracted `tar.gz`
with `cd -Folderdestination/` you locate a folderwhere you keep a file named cytoscape.sh, and with command

`sudo sh cytoscape.sh`

install the program.

Answer (score 0):

Once java 11 is installed on your computer try this:

1. ctrl+alt+T                           #open Ubuntu's console
2. cd /home/fulanita/Downloads         #this is the directory where my computer has cytoscape.
3. chmod +x ./Cytoscape_3_8_1_unix.sh
4. ./Cytoscape_3_8_1_unix.sh            #3.8.1 is the last version for Ubuntu

the program will start to install